# Download Table from PRR drug Research tool

Tags: openfda

I used the PRR drug research tool: https://openfda.shinyapps.io/RR_D/ 
When I select a drug name it lists me by default the top 50 drug event combinations with PRR & ROR values. 
In the R shiny app there isn't any download button being designed.

How can I download the table with PRR & ROR values?

Comment: whats a drug name you select?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the download functionality is unavailable in the shiny app you mentioned.